# VB extension property instead of extension method

Tags: vb.net, properties

I saw [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4809011/c-sharp-extension-property-instead-of-extension-method) and I want to know if this is possible in VB.

So like extension method, do extension properties exists in VB.Net?

[Here](http://forums.silverlight.net/t/174767.aspx/1) I've read they do, but cannot find any examples.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe that person is incorrect. [From MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384936.aspx)

> You cannot define an extension property, field, or event.

Comment: Correct. This was never supported.

Comment: VB.NET has the (un)fortunate functionality of allowing you to omit empty parameters of a method, which also works for extension methods, so you could write an extension method and make it *look* like an extension property.

Answer (score 3):

This is *almost possible*.  Learned this neat trick from Daniel Cazzulino.

You return a type from an extension method which exposes the properties.  This is C#, but should be understandable.

```cs
public static class ListExtensions
{
    // this extension method returns the type with properties
    public static ListExtender<T> Extend<T>(this List<T> target)
    {
        //null check skipped
        return new ListExtender<T>(target);
    }
}

public sealed class ListExtender<T>
{
    private List<T> _target;

    // this is a pseudo extension property
    public T First { get { return _target[0]; } }

    public ListExtender(List<T> target)
    {
        _target = target;
    }
}
```

Other than that, the answer is no.

Answer (score 0):

According to the MSDN(draft) [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384936%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for Visual Studio 11, extension properties are not available in VS 11 (i.e., .NET 4.5) either.

It's odd though searching does throw up a few instances where bloggers, etc., think it to be possible, including Ayende in an article on his blog [here](http://ayende.com/blog/2992/why-c-doesnt-have-extension-properties).

Comment: It is very weird indeed, I wonder what they are doing then if they think it's expansion properties.